# ssh to different nodes using shell scripting

Tags: linux, shell, ssh

I am using below code to ssh to different nodes and find if an user exists or not. If the user doesn't exist it will create it.

The script works fine if I don't do ssh but it fails if I do ssh.

How can I go through different nodes using this script?

```
for node in `nodes.txt`
usr=root

ssh $usr@$node 
do
if [ $(id -u) -eq 0 ]; then
    read -p "Enter username : " username
    read -s -p "Enter password : " password
    egrep "^$username" /etc/passwd >/dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "$username exists!"
        exit 1
    else
        pass=$(perl -e 'print crypt($ARGV[0], "password")' $password)
        useradd -m -p $pass $username
        [ $? -eq 0 ] && echo "User has been added to system!" || echo "F
ailed to add a user!"
    fi
else
    echo "Only root may add a user to the system"
    exit 2
fi
done
```

Comment: Why are you adding the user without home folder? Try to create the user without -m flag in the useradd command.

Answer (score 1):

Your script has grave syntax errors.  I guess the `for` loop at the beginning is what you attempted to add but you totally broke the script in the process.

The syntax for looping over lines in a file is

```
while read -r line; do
    .... # loop over "$line"
done <nodes.txt
```

(or marginally `for line in $(cat nodes.txt); do` ... but this has multiple issues; see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor for details).

If the intent is to actually run the remainder of the script in the `ssh` you need to pass it to the `ssh` command.  Something like this:

```
while read -r node; do
   read -p "Enter user name: " username
   read -p -s "Enter password: "
   ssh root@"$node" "
       # Note addition of -q option and trailing :
       egrep -q '^$username:' /etc/passwd ||
       useradd -m -p \"\$(perl -e 'print crypt(\$ARGV[0], \"password\")' \"$password\")" '$username'" </dev/null
done <nodes.txt
```

Granted, the command you pass to `ssh` can be arbitrarily complex, but you will want to avoid doing interactive I/O inside a root-privileged remote script, and generally make sure the remote command is as quiet and robust as possible.

The anti-pattern `command; if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then ...` is clumsy but very common.  The purpose of `if` is to run a command and examine its result code, so this is better and more idiomatically written `if command; then ...` (which can be even more succinctly written `command && ...` or `! command || ...` if you only need the `then` or the `else` part, respectively, of the full long-hand `if`/`then`/`else` structure).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. issue is not with the loop. issue is i am not able to ssh on diff nodes and perform the task that were written in the script.

Comment: Then your question is unclear/too broad. Editing the question significantly at this point may be inadvisable; perhaps simply post a new question with a proper [mcve], though it's likely to be a duplicate of an existing question.

Comment: See [the Stack Overflow  `bash` tag wiki](/tags/bash/info) for some common FAQs.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should only do the remote tasks via ssh. All the rest runs local.

```
ssh $user@$node egrep "^$username" /etc/passwd >/dev/null
```

and

```
ssh $user@$node useradd -m -p $pass $username
```

It might also be better to ask for username and password outside of the loop if you want to create the same user on all nodes.